# Passing an Id value to Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a View with the name 'Details' which contains a partial view 'PostReply'. I m trying to pass an Id from Details view to PostReply Controller action.

I have tried this in Details view, but it pushes null value of id.

```
@Html.Partial("PostReply", new XXXXX.Models.Reply{ QuestionId = Model.Question.ID })
```

Then I tried adding an id value to BeginForm in PostReply(Partial View) like this:

```
Html.BeginForm("PostReply", "Question", new { id = Model.Question.ID}))
```

This also doesn't work. How can I get id value from details to PostReply? Thanks in advance.

**Details View:**

```
@model XXXXXX.Models.ParentView.Questions
....
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.QuestionModel.Title)
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.QuestionModel.Desc)
....
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.QuestionModel.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
....
@Html.Partial("PostReply", new Chemtalks.Models.Reply())
```

**PostReply (Partial View):**

```
@model XXXXX.Models.Reply
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostReply", "Question", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReplyText)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReplyText)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReplyText

    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

**Details & PostReply Controllers:**

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    var model = new ParentView.Questions
    {
        QuestionModel = db.QuestionModels.Find(id),
        Reply = db.Replies.Where(t => t.QuestionId == id)
    };
    if (model == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult PostReply([Bind(Include = "ReplyID, ReplyText, UserID, QuestionId")] Reply reply, int? id)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            reply.QuestionId = id;
            reply.UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            db.Replies.Add(reply);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (DataException)
    {

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to post your reply. Please try again later.");
    }

    return PartialView(reply);
}
```

QuestionModel:

```
public class QuestionModels
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("QuestionId")]
    public virtual ICollection<Reply> Replies { get; set; }
}

public class Reply
{
    public int ReplyID { get; set; }
    public string ReplyText { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public int? QuestionId { get; set; }
    public virtual QuestionModels QuestionsModels { get; set; }
}
```

**ParentView Model:**

```
public class ParentView
{
    public class Questions
    {
        public QuestionModels QuestionModel { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Reply> Reply { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have not shown your models but `new XXXXX.Models.Reply { QuestionId = Model.Question.ID })` means `Reply` contains a property named `QuestionId` so I'm guessing your want `new { id = Model.QuestionId }` in your form (not `Model.Question.ID` which would likely throw a NullReferenceException)

Comment: I have added models too. QuestionId is a foreign key in a table Reply and I m trying to populate it with the ID of Questionmodel table

Comment: Let me edit and remove all the irrelevant code first.

Comment: The model in the main view is `Questions`, so to add the route parameter, it would need to be `@Html.Partial("PostReply", new Chemtalks.Models.Reply { QuestionId = Model.QuestionModel.ID })` and then `Html.BeginForm("PostReply", "Question", new { QuestionId = Model.QuestionId }))`

Comment: It doesn't work. The code is not assigning value of QuestionId at the Details view level. Is there any other way around?

Comment: What do you mean _at the Details view level_? And it does work so I have idea what else you doing wrong. Debug your code including the view and check the values your passing.

Comment: What does the accepted answer possibly have to do with your question? You do not need `@Html.Action()` to pass a model to a partial (there is no reason at all to call a server method)

Comment: Changing '@Html.Parital' to '@Html.Action' has allowed the controller to get an id value. I have tried this multiple times, but still I m unable to get an ID value from the solution you provided. I don't know why it is not allowing it through '@Html.Partial'. Confused. Have already debug the solution. I don't find any problem in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `@Html.Action` method in order to render a partial view and run a child action for it. `@Html.Partial` does not invoke any action method.

So, rendering of the child view should look like

```
@Html.Action("PostReply", new XXXXX.Models.Reply{ QuestionId = Model.Question.ID })
```

and the child action in the controller does not work with attribute `[HttpPost]`. It is better to remove it together with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`.

It is a good practice to use such kind of actions with the `[ChildActionOnly]` attribute in order to forbid calling the action as a result of a direct request.

**UPDATE:**
Sorry, I thought you need to get some data from the action to render the view, but after Stephen Muecke's comment I realized that you don't need that. So, in general you should use what Stephen suggested

```
@Html.Partial("PostReply", new Chemtalks.Models.Reply { QuestionId = Model.QuestionModel.ID })
```

and then

```
Html.BeginForm("PostReply", "Question", new { QuestionId = Model.QuestionId })
```

or you can add a hidden field to your PostReply form instead of the route parameter

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuestionId)
```

The approach with the route parameter could not work if you use a wrong `BeginForm` overload e.g. this one

```
Html.BeginForm("PostReply", "Question", FormMethod.Post, new {QuestionId = Model.QuestionId})
```

Comment: But I have a question, I have deleted ValidateAntiForgeryToken and HttpPost and also cannot use ChildActionOnly, because on creating a post, there is an error occurred which says 'The action 'PostReply' is accessible only by a child request.'. Is it save to use controller without forbidding calls?

Comment: I would prefer not to post to the child action. You could create another action that is available from the outside and has [HttpPost], [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attributes and you could post to that action. The common part of two actions could be extracted into a separate method or one action could be called from another.

Comment: I don't know why but it is not allowing me to have id value in controller on using @html.Partial in my Details View. Any idea?